# Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store vs Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store

Tags: .net, azure, azure-data-lake

I just started working with Azure Data Lake in .NET. I found there are 2 libraries available:

**Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store**
Provides Data Lake Store
Account and filesystem management capabilities for Microsoft Azure.

**Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store**
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Store Filesystem Library for Dot Net

Both of these libraries work with FileSystem, which one should I use?

Comment: One provides *management* capabilities, the other the *Filesystem library*. Just like the descriptions state. So, if you want to manage your Data Lake Store, take the first one. If you want to read/write there, use the second.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Doc here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data-lake-store?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store is the current supported dataplane (read/write/manage Acls) sdk. Dataplane of the Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store is not supported, only management plane of the Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store is supported.

Reasons for using Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store over dataplane of Microsoft.Azure.Management.DataLake.Store:

1. Internally embeds best practices that otherwise have to be programmed by each customer explicitly (we have found this to be frequent source of issues in customer code)
   a.  Bad offset recovery
   b.  syncFlag management
   c.  file-level leases and session IDs
   d.  grouping reads and writes to block sizes
   e.  Retry policies that work best with the service and the specific API’s semantics
   f.  Client-side getContentSummary
   g.  Paged file enumeration
2. Easier programming model
   a.  ACLs as first-class objects rather than strings
   b.  Reader and writer Streams for the file that internally do paged reads/writes
   c.  IEnumerable for file enumeration using iterators or for doing filtering using Linq
   d.  Client object rather than calling each method with account name
3. Better performance on bulk file uploads/downloads
4. Support for new features
   a.  recursive ACLs
5. This is where all our future investments will be.

Comment: Is Microsoft.Azure.DataLake.Store compatible with Azure DataLakes Gen2? or it is only supported for Gen1?  If not, is there an SDK available for Gen2?